# Finding first element from list in java 8

Tags: list, java-8

How to write this type of code in java 8? I want to write this in Java8 using stream. Is there any way for this?

```
List<SomeDTO> someDTOList = sample.getSomeDTO();
int a=0;
for(SomeDTO sample : someDTOList  ){
    String someElement = sample .getSomeElement ();
    if(someElement.equals("Condition1"){
        a=1;
        break;
    }
    if(someElement.equals("Condition2"){
        a=2;
        break;
    }
    if(someElement.equals("Condition3"){
        a=3;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is sample doing? whst is not working? explain your question is detail

Comment: Rather than asking other people to do your assignment for you, attempt to write it yourself and ask here if you run into an actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of `map`, `mapToInt`, `filter` and `findFirst`, but it won't be so pretty :

```
int a =
    sample.getSomeDTO()
          .stream()
          .map(SomeDTO::getSomeElement)
          .mapToInt(e -> {
               if (e.equals("Condition1"))
                   return 1;
               else if (e.equals("Condition2"))
                   return 2;
               else if (e.equals("Condition3"))
                   return 3;
               else
                   return 0;
           })
          .filter(a -> a > 0)
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(0);
```

As Holger suggested, you can make it less ugly by replacing the if statements with ternary conditional expressions :

```
int a =
    sample.getSomeDTO()
          .stream()
          .map(SomeDTO::getSomeElement)
          .mapToInt(e -> e.equals("Condition1") ? 1 : e.equals("Condition2") ? 2 : e.equals("Condition3") ? 3 : 0)
          .filter(a -> a > 0)
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(0);
```

Comment: `.mapToInt(e -> e.equals("Condition1")? 1: e.equals("Condition2")? 2: e.equals("Condition3")? 3: 0)`

Comment: @Holger Much better :)